# Syntax for generating Barcode using PCL syntax

Tags: java, printing, printer-control-language

Iam searching for a PCL syntax to generate and print the BARCODE. If anyone having any information about the same, please help me. I have tried googling it, but didnt find anything.

Comment: Can someone please provide any guidance on this?

Comment: can you provide more details on your requirement. Do you have an input barcode as an image of some sort? Do you want to create an output which is a standard page (like an A4 or letter page) with just the barcode as content?

Comment: Currently we are printing some details on A4 page. I want to print the barcode on the same page. Now, all the details are coded using PCL syntax and to print barcode I will need to do the same. Anyhelp regarding this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a barcode font.  Once you have this simply move the cursor to the spot you want (in the example 300 x 300 in whatever unit of measure you've defined), and then call the barocde and put your text down.  A simple exmample might look like htis:

```
<ESC>*p300x300Y<ESC>*c100D1234567890
```

This assumes that you have embedded the barcode as part of the print job and assigned the numeric 1000 to the font call.  Just search the web for "pcl barcode font" and you will find many sites that sell these fonts and provide instructions on how to call.  If the printer has barcode fonts embedded, try printing a font list and it should provide the escape sequence you need to call.

Comment: Hi Douglas, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried using this soft font approach previously and it worked. But, I am looking out for some other approach which doesn't include downloading a font to the printer as we have many users accessing our web application and would not like user to download a font.

Comment: Is this a dynamic barcode or static?  If it is staic then you could simply create the graphic image as a bitmap and embed it, or if you are really creative you could do the math and create the barcode using lines/dots in PCL on the fly.

Comment: It's a dynamic barcode that we need to print. I looked into Raster Graphics of PCL. But it requires us to pass a binary data row by row in order to print it which is not possible if we have a dynamic barcode. Buying a soft font is out of scope as it requires global license which is way too expensive. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: What barcode is it you are looking for?  I can probably direct you to a very inexpensive one.

Comment: I'm looking for Code 39 barcode. Please redirect me to the inexpensive one?